# Filter data according to dropdown option reacts

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am kinda new to Reactjs. I am trying to implement an app where data is displayed in home page and a dropdown with options in it. On click of an option the data should be filtered accordingly and the filtered data should replace original data.

Can someone please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Priscilla, I think the best way to an accurate answer here is for you to share a repo or the piece of code you are having issues with because your question is too broad and it can be implemented in a couple of different ways

Comment: Could you show a simple way with simple data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is very simple example @Priscilla:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const categories = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"];
const products = [
  { id: "1", name: "Product 1", category: "cat1" },
  { id: "2", name: "Product 2", category: "cat1" },
  { id: "3", name: "Product 3", category: "cat1" },
  { id: "4", name: "Product 4", category: "cat2" },
  { id: "5", name: "Product 5", category: "cat2" },
  { id: "6", name: "Product 6", category: "cat2" },
  { id: "7", name: "Product 7", category: "cat3" },
  { id: "8", name: "Product 8", category: "cat3" },
  { id: "9", name: "Product 9", category: "cat3" },
  { id: "10", name: "Product 10", category: "cat3" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

  const filterProducts = function (event) {
    const prods = products.filter((p) => p.category === event.target.value);
    console.log(prods);

    setFilteredProducts(prods);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <select onChange={(event) => filterProducts(event)}>
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
        {categories.map((c) => (
          <option key={c} value={c}>
            {c}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <ul>
        {filteredProducts.map((p) => (
          <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can play with it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-bush-urssn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Is there a way that initially it displays every data then on dropdown  select it replaces the filtered one?

Comment: Yes there is, can change this like to assign an initial value: const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState(products);